# What is this search algorithm called?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, skip-lists

I recently encountered an algorithm for searching for numbers in a sorted list and this is how it goes:

Given: An oracle that tells you if a given number greater than or less than the number being searched for.

Begin at first element in the list. Skip 1 element ahead and ask the oracle if you have gone ahead of the number being searched for.

If not, ask skip 2 elements and ask the oracle if you have gone too far.

If not skip 4 elements ahead, etc....

When you find the first skip that causes you to pass over the number being searched for, you can determine a subinterval that contains the number being searched for.

Finally, perform binary search on the subinterval.

I was wondering what this algorithm was called so that I might be able to do some more research on it.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you would do this? It seems to me that there's a 50% chance the subinterval found will just be the last half of the list, and thus could have been found in just one step of a binary search.

Comment: [This article](https://sites.google.com/site/d7013e11/announcements/exponentialbinarysearch) calls it an _exponential binary search_.

Comment: @ImreKerr A very good question, I can imagine only one case where binary search is not applicable/better: When the number of items is unbounded or not know ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how you binary search an unbounded set.

For example, to solve an inequality `f(n) < t` over the positive integers, where f is an increasing function.

Concrete example:

```
Solve n**2 + 10*n < 100 over the positive integers.

Let f(n) = n**2 + 10*n for n > 0
f is increasing because it's the sum of increasing functions.

f(1) = 1 + 10 = 11
f(2) = 4 + 20 = 24
f(4) = 16 + 40 = 56
f(8) = 64 + 80 = 144 > 100

Now we binary search the interval [4,8]

f(6) = 36 + 60 = 96
f(7) = 49 + 70 = 119 > 100

Thus n < 7
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was referring to!

Answer (score 0):

This data structure is called [Skip Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

[image]

> A skip list is a data structure for storing a sorted list of items
>   using a hierarchy of linked lists that connect increasingly sparse
>   subsequences of the items. These auxiliary lists allow item lookup
>   with efficiency comparable to balanced binary search trees (that is,
>   with number of probes proportional to log n instead of n).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was not referring to skip lists. I apologize if my description was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest few changes in the algorithm. There should be 2 iterators one following the other and when you realize that you have move to a list node which has greater number than the number being searched..we should restart the same steps with the previous iterator..this goes on till we find the number..because i dont understand how would to do a binary serch i.e in log(N) time with a list...